# Raspberry Pi OpenVPN - Clients unable to see network devices

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, openvpn, raspberry-pi

I have completed the setup of OpenVpn on my raspberry pi. I am able to connect successfully and access the internet as if I'm browsing from home.

My problem is that I have a network share that I want to be able to access while connected to the VPN, but the clients are unable to see this network share or any other devices on the network except for the device itself.

I have noticed that when my laptop is connected to my home network, these are it's connection settings:

```
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.12.19
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.12.254
```

While connected through the VPN my laptop has:

```
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.43.11
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.43.1
```

The raspberry pi has a static ip address of 192.168.12.18

I would really appreciate any help as I'm really stuck.

Andrew